# Mac modifier keys are automatically getting restored to default bindings the next day

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

So everyday, I change the preferences of modifier keys and set my caps lock to be the control key. The very next day, it comes back to being caps lock again.

This was a brand new 15 inch Macbook pro with Yosemite in it. I haven't installed any third party Mac app except for my development environment which includes - brew, emacs, jdk, vagrant, ansible, virtualbox. That's it. I did install few fonts but have not installed anything special.

Also, I made chrome my default browser and next day links on are again opening in Safari.

Is there some background service that might be restoring it back to normal ? I have no idea how to diagnose this behavior.

Comment: Are you using a guest account?

Comment: No. It's my own account with my username. Also, I have not even shut down the machine yet.